# MVC Razor pass complex parameters from jquery to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a popup in which there is a textbox and a bunch of checkboxes. I have given all the checkboxes a value and these values are stored in an array.
Now i want to pass this array and textbox value from Jquery to controller action. How can i do this ?
I have tried on stackoverflow by all the keywords, but it doesn't work...

My jquery data is as follws:

```
$("#submit-button").click(function () {
    var AccessBit = new Array(7);
    AccessBit = BitLogic();  // integer array returned from BitLogic method
    var role = $("#RoleName").val();  // Textbox value
    var json = JSON.stringify(AccessBit);
    alert(AccessBit);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Role/BitLogic",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: json,

        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });

    $("#createForm").dialog("close");
});
```

and Controller is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public void BitLogic(int[][] AccessBit)
{

}
```

How can i pass role value along with Accesbit array ?
AccessBit is two dimensional integer array.

Comment: Is you array successfully passed to controller ?

Comment: yes my array is successfully passed to controller in this way...

Comment: AccessBit ? show the code of accessbit

Comment: AccessBit has a quite complex structure... u can't understand without full description... and I am receiving AccesBit array as i want... The main concern is how pass to pass Accesbit along with RoleName to Controller

Comment: Create a second parameter in you post method (say `string role`) and include in your ajax data parameter

Comment: @Stephen => can u give me full way to do this

Comment: Add this in your ajax call JSON.stringify({ AccessBit: AccessBit, role : role  }) in your json variable,and in your controller add one parameter like this public void BitLogic(int[][] AccessBit,string role)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an additional parameter in you POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public void BitLogic(int[][] AccessBit, string role)
{
  ....
}
```

Then pass the value in your ajax function

```
$.ajax({
  .....
  data: JSON.stringify({ AccessBit: AccessBit, role: role }),
```

Credit also to Mairaj Ahmad